# Getting EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION when starting tomcat under eclipse, windows 10

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle

This has been working. Of course I've made changes, but don't know any that point in the direction the error message would indicate.

I have a Java Spring Batch application and a web app for starting any of several batch jobs. I am on eclipse photon 4.8.0, running windows 10, java 1.8, and Tomcat 7.0.59. When I start the server, the console shows normal INFO output through "Initialization processed in 2538 ms", then

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006d3130a2, pid=18012, tid=20820
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_51-b16) (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.51-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x1430a2]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

and lists an error report file. In that, I see a stack dump including:

```
j  oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.t2cSetSessionTimeZone(JLjava/lang/String;)I+0
j  oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon()V+835
j  oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;Loracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriverExtension;)V+324
j  oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;Loracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriverExtension;)V+4
j  oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)Ljava/sql/Connection;+34
j  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)Ljava/sql/Connection;+299
j  org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver()V+313
j  org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect()V+91
j  org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(JLorg/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PooledConnection;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PooledConnection;+55
j  org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PooledConnection;+119
j  org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(Lorg/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PoolConfiguration;)V+554
```

I upgraded my (minor) version of Java and configured the server to run that, but get the same error. Is anyone aware of some kind of compatibility problem or something that causes this?

Comment: Did you try to use different types of JVMs? The error indicates that your local tomcat configuration has an issue with the jvm.dll, perhaps a different JVM will succeed....

Comment: I'm constrained in the Java tool I use by the company -- had to get special permission to upgrade the version. And it did run with this version of the Java before.

Comment: What about removing the current java version and reinstalling it? on the off chance that the JVM was somehow corrupted....

Comment: I got the special permission and installed the newest version of java, and switched the server over to using it. Got the same error, don't think it's the java install.

Comment: How about redefining the tomcat server in eclipse?

Comment: Since I posted, I created a new server, slightly upgraded minor version of Tomcat 7 -- same result.

Comment: Possible memory issues? Did you check if your JVM is running out of memory?